# .net core web api assembly binding redirects

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, assembly-binding-redirect

I've looked at various solutions online about binding redirects in a .NET Core 2.0 / 2.1 web api application.

My understanding is (was) that all you need to do is add an app.config file to your  project with the redirects and it all works.

I tried this, and it didn't work at all, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Core" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="null" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.18186.03" newVersion="5.0.18137.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Instead I then programmatically redirected the assembly to the required version, and it worked fine.

How do you correctly perform binding redirects in a web api .NET Core 2.0 app?

The reason I need this is because of third party assembly issues. I have been given a set of assemblies to use for common functions. One of these assemblies has been upgraded to version 5.0.18186.03, but it depends on other lower level assemblies (Common.Core in the Xml example). The whole suite was recompiled to version 5.0.18186.03 but only the assembly I use has been officially released. However when this assembly is used .NET falls over saying it can't find the correct version of Common.Core that matches version 5.0.18186.03,

A hardcoded binding redirect fixes this as the new version of Common.Core is functionally exactly the same as the old version.

I don't really understand one of the comments - "why do you need this"? Eventually, something like binding redirects is always going to be needed.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? .NET Core introduced a different dependency model that should no longer require binding redirects. Also, neither App.config nor Web.config are utilized by .NET Core/ASP.NET Core. Why do you feel you need binding redirects?

Comment: I've had the problem on a number of occasions now. Package X uses version 1.0, Package Y uses version 1.1 and either the compiler fails or the program crashes at runtime. I *know* that 1.1 and 1.0 have the same api and will work fine... Binding redirects was the way around this. I think a deps file is needed but documentation is sparse on this. I'm surprised that this kind of information is so hard to find.